# Pulsar does a infinite redelivery of message when maxredelivery count is breached for DLQ

Tags: apache-pulsar, pulsar

I have simple setup where in i have pulasr consumer subscribing to a topic with DLQ of maxredelivery count= 2 on shared subscription type.

So when the message is consumed we send the message via websocket to get a ack, but since the message is to big the websocket closes the subscribed consumer and reconnects and creates the same consumer subscriber again.

So i see the redelivery count from broker keep on increasing infinitly even when maxredelivery count is set to 2.

I browsered a lot on this problem with could not find anything

Comment: How big is the message?

Comment: @DavidKjerrumgaard thank you for your reply. The message is 32 MB. Following the post, I created my own stomp client (As the client side issue). I tried to mimic the same with my stomp client and observed the following behavior.  When the stomp client receives the message I manually disconnect the connection, so the consumer created on the stomp session at the stomp server side is also closed. And I immediately reconnect and recreate the pulsar consumer. So I saw that the broker resend the message infinitely as the consumer was not allowed to send anything to DLQ as it was never in the open.